# The background color of TabLayout is not animated with the parent animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an AppBarLayout with a toolbar and a tablayout. I want to apply the enter animation for the tabLayout like Google's Youtube app.

In the activity's onCreate() I use:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tabLayout, View.Y, 150f, 200f)
```

However, the slide animation only applies to the tab title. The primary (background) color of the tabLayout is not animated. It's always there.

Here's what I tried:

1. Use LayoutAnimation on a separate layout of tabLayout, say FrameLayout.
2. Remove the background of tablayout.

None of them works. Any suggestions?

Update screenshot:

The green background is not animated with the titles:

[image: The tablayout's background is not animated with the titles]

Answer (score 0):

if you want enter animation for your tablayout as in youtube app.just put this code in onResume() of your activity and not in onCreate().

```
int size=this.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.enterheight);
//size is in pixels 
    ObjectAnimator object1=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tablayout,"translationY",-size,0);
    object1.setDuration(500);
    object1.start();
```

works fine in my app.If you want some more animations to run in addition to this enter animation use AnimationSet.